# Fully qualified context name (two dots)

Tags: kdb

What do they mean (for example in https://code.kx.com/q/ref/key/) when reffering global contexts variable `a` with two dots:

```
q)a:1
q)get `..a
1
```

Why this address points exactly to the root namespace variable `a`?

**Upd**:

Thanks to @terrylynch answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61792207/689990, finally got it! The name of root namespace is

```
`.
```

as the name of namespace `.foo` is:

```
`.foo
```

So just adding `.a` gives

```
`..a
`.foo.a
```

as s result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page explains it better: https://code.kx.com/q4m3/12_Workspace_Organization/#121-namespaces

A general dictionary  (non uniform values) and a namespace (which is essentially a general dictionary) can use dot notation to access its values

```
q)d:``a`b!(::;1;2)
q)d
 | ::
a| 1
b| 2
q)d.a
1
q)\d .foo
q.foo)a:11
q.foo)\d .
q)
q).foo.a
11
```

Another way to access such values is

```
q)`.foo[`a]
11
q)get`.foo.a
11
```

But since `` `. `` is the root namespace, it follows that

```
q)a:100
q)`.[`a]
100
q)get`..a
100
```